# Converge almost surely with sums of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $A_{1},A_{2},...$ be a sequence of independent events, and let $b_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i})$. If $b_{n}\to \infty$, then 
$\frac{1}{b_{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{A_{i}}\to 1$ a.s. 
How can I prove it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can prove that this sequence has expectation $1$ and that its variance goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. However I think that this argument only gives convergence in $L^2$. To get almost sure convergence, I think it is necessary to use Borel-Cantelli lemma but I'm not sure of how for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hint.

1. Let $n_k:=\inf\{n\geqslant 1, b_n\geqslant k^2\}$. We can show via the classical Borel-Cantelli lemma that $\frac{1}{b_{n_k}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}I_{A_{i}}\to 1$ a.s.
2. To get the convergence for the whole sequence, we have to show the convergence to $0$ of
   $$
   \max_{n_k\leqslant n\leqslant n_{k+1}-1}\left\lvert \frac{1}{b_{n }}\sum_{i=1}^{n }I_{A_{i}}-\frac{1}{b_{n_k}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}I_{A_{i}}\right\rvert.
   $$
   What is annoying is that the normalization for $\sum_{i=1}^{n }I_{A_{i}}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n_k }I_{A_{i}}$ is not the same. but we can write
   $$
   \max_{n_k\leqslant n\leqslant n_{k+1}-1}\left\lvert \frac{1}{b_{n }}\sum_{i=1}^{n }I_{A_{i}}-\frac{1}{b_{n_k}}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}I_{A_{i}}\right\rvert\leqslant 
   \max_{n_k\leqslant n\leqslant n_{k+1}-1}\left\lvert \frac{1}{b_{n }}\sum_{i=1}^{n }I_{A_{i}}-\frac{1}{b_{n_k}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_{A_{i}}\right\rvert
   +\max_{n_k\leqslant n\leqslant n_{k+1}-1}\left\lvert \frac{1}{b_{n_k}}\sum_{i=n_k+1}^{n}I_{A_{i}}\right\rvert
   $$
   and apply Kolmorogov's maximal inequality to both terms.